# Manipulate pixels before drawing on the canvas

Tags: html, canvas, alpha

I'm using the following code to draw a base64 image on the canvas. I get the base64 string from a query in PHP. With globalAlpha i can set the alpha of the whole image to 0. I need to manipulate the alpha of random pixels with a form. So when I submit 7 with the form, 7 random pixels need to be set from alpha 0 to 255.

Is it possible to manipulate the alpha of this image and after that, draw it to the canvas? It's very important that the original image remains secret.

```
var complex = "<?php echo str_replace("\n", "", $DBimage); ?>";
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image = new Image();
image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + complex;
image.onload= function(){
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry! Have tested it but totally forgot to comment.

Comment: well.. I kinda does, but I'm not sure what exactly happens. I could put my new code here.. .but where's the best spot to do so. In a new answer or editing my first post?

Comment: in a jsfiddle or in your answer with an "edit" note, to keep your first question as it was

Answer (score 0):

```
<canvas id="rectangle" width="300" height="300" style="border:solid black 1px; </canvas>
​
```

the javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('rectangle');
//replace this rectangle drawing by your image
if (canvas.getContext) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.fillStyle = "rgb(150,29,28)";
    context.fillRect(10, 10, 280, 280);
}

var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var numberOfAlphaPix = 10000; //this is the number of pixel for which you want to change the alpha channel, I let you do the job to retrieve this number as you wish

//fill an array with numbers that we'll pop to get unique random values
var rand = [];

// Loop over each pixel with step of 4 to store only alpha channel in array ( R=0 ,G=1 , B=2, A=3 )
for (var i = 3; i < imgd.data.length; i += 4) {
    rand.push(i);
}

//shuffle the array
for (var i = rand.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var tmp = rand[i];
        rand[i] = rand[j];
        rand[j] = tmp;
}


for (var i = 0; i < numberOfAlphaPix; i++) {
    imgd.data[rand.pop()] = 255; //set alpha channel to 255
}

// Draw the ImageData object at the given (x,y) coordinates.
context.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);​
```

Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/LuEzG/5/

Comment: I did test this code but it doesn't work yet. The canvas stays empty, no matter what I use for i. If I remove the line 'var rand []', the picture is drawn to the canvas. Besides this, is it possible to hide the base64 code. It's important that the original picture stays secret and that anyone can't guess what the final picture is going to be.

Comment: As I said I had not tested it, it was just an algorithm for you to work with. 
I update the answer and give you the stuff that works

Comment: Thank! I did some testing with the square. One thing I don't get is the fillStyle. If I change this to black(0,0,0), the pixels that get a alpha of 255 become red. Where does the red color come from?

Comment: My bad, change this line " for (var i = 4; i < imgd.data.length; i += 4) {
    rand.push(i);
} " and set var i =3 ( because pixel start at 0, r=0,g=1,b=2,a=3 )

Comment: well.. it's not yet right in my opinion.Changing 'imgd.data[rand.pop()] = 1;' to 'imgd.data[rand.pop()] = 0;' doesn't change the output. Besides that, an alpha of 255 (1) Should set the pixels opaque and not transparent.

Comment: fiddle is not right it is from 0 to 255 even for alpha channel, sorry about that. 
Now I can't code your app entirely, I gave you something that works and answer your question, I'm not sure what more I can do

Comment: I know.. I really appreciate your help. I did a lot of testing but didn't come any further. But I think I've got this thing working now.

Many thanks.

Comment: I thought it went very well.. but the alpha thing doesn't seem to work with pictures.
Here's how I want it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/LuEzG/11/
This is with a picture: http://jsfiddle.net/LuEzG/12/

It can set the alpha for the complete picture in the canvas to 0, but it looks like that pixels are not being recognized after that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean "stay secret", but I think you mean:

1. show only a few pixels at a time
2. Make it impossible for people to view source and discover the image (with a bit of JavaScript)

If those are the only requirements (And if they are requirements) then you'll have to:

1. decode the image on the server
2. Pick a few random pixels on the server and send the data for those pixels (RGB values) to the client
3. Use canvas to show those few pixels that were received

The nice thing about this approach is that you don't need to use ImageData at all. You can just `fillRect` with a `fillStyle` of the RGB values for each pixel recieved.

The not-so-nice thing about this approach is that it means you have to do a lot more work on the server, **but if you want the image to be completely hidden from the client, it's the only way.**

Comment: I figured out that I had to do the manipulation server-side with the PHP GD library.

Comment: I found a way to do it with PHP GD. It's not yet working 100% but i'm getting there. The script I'm working on can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554634/single-pixel-manipulation-with-php-gd/13584484#13584484)